# How to draw multiple texts on canvas

Tags: android, canvas, drawing

I've created a drawing app and now I'm trying to allow the user to add text to the drawing. The text will be placed anywhere on the screen where the user touches with his finger. With the following code, the text could be drawn on screen with the drawing. However, this is only done once. The moment I tap on the screen, the previous text disappears and the new text is placed at my current finger position.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawColor(canvasColor);  


    for(Pair<Path, Paint> p : paths){
        canvas.drawPath(p.first, p.second);
        }
        canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);

    if(textCB && !pbCol)
    {
        tPaint = new Paint();
        tPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
        tPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        tPaint.setColor(tColor);
        canvas.drawText(addText, tx, ty, tPaint);
    }


}
```

What can I do to allow multiple text to be drawn on the canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a way to do this. After drawing the text, I got the bitmap from getDrawingCache, then drew the bitmap onto the canvas.